# Photoshop px vs. OS px

Tags: photoshop, pixel

While converting a webdesign given as a photoshop file to html+css, I got confused with font sizes. As seen on the image below, 30 px in photoshop does not equal 30 px in other Windows programs (different on Mac or others?), or browsers. This seems to be unaffected by creating the photoshop image in different resolutions than 72 which is default, and unaffected by change of units between pt and px. Can anyone hint on how to set photoshop to use browser px units?
[image]

Comment: Do you find that Paint matches the size in the browser? I would think it doesn't - Paint can't use px.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The font size in the paint document refers to points, not pixels. Change the font size in photoshop to 30pt and they should be the same size.

A point is 1/72 of an inch and the pixel equivalent can depend on the DPI of your monitor. At 96 DPI 30pt * 1in/72pt * 96DPI (my screen res) is 40px. To convert pixels to points work backwards so 30px * 1in/96px * 72pt/1in = 22.5pt.

So change the paint text size to 22.5 and they should match up.

Comment: Windows usually uses 96 DPI for the monitor, regardless of the actual physical DPI of the monitor. Your image DPI must match for the point sizes to match. But that still doesn't answer the question of how to make the size match HTML/CSS, because Paint won't match either.

Comment: The problem though is that he's comparing pixels to points. The conversion between the two depends on the dpi of both the image and the screen.

Comment: See my comparison here: (I don't have photoshop on this computer otherwise I would use that.) http://kimag.es/share/7986640.png

Comment: Thanks for that picture. It looks like Photoshop px are pretty close to HTML/CSS px after all.

Answer (score 1):

Set it to 96 dpi.

Comment: Operating systems don't actually calibrate the physical size of your monitor. Instead, they make standard guess about resolution. On Windows, the standard guess the OS makes about the screen resolution is 96 dpi. On Mac OS the standard guess is 72 dpi.

Comment: That would only help if using points for the text size, not px.